# Realmswift generic function call crashes when Result<Object> is returned

Tags: ios, swift, generics, realm

I have built a generic function to get any kind of data from realm, that seems to work just fine.

```
 func getData<T: Object>(withFilter: String) -> Results<T>? {
    if !checkRealm(){return nil}
    return realm!.objects(T.self).filter(withFilter)
}
```

I can't figure out though how to use this function to delete data.
My delete function is the following:

```
    func removeData(withFilter: String) {

        let dataToDelete: Results<Object>? = getData(withFilter: withFilter)
        // *** The above line crashes the app ***

        if let dataToDeleteUnwrapped = dataToDelete{
            try? realm!.write {
                realm!.delete(dataToDeleteUnwrapped)
            }
    }
}
```

This results to an error, attached bellow. Though `Results<Object>?` crashes the app, `Results<MyCustomObject>?` works fine, but then my remove data function is not generic anymore.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Object type 'RealmSwiftObject' is not managed by the Realm. If using a custom `objectClasses` / `objectTypes` array in your configuration, add `RealmSwiftObject` to the list of `objectClasses` / `objectTypes`.'
```

I am sure there is a nice short way to solve this one, but I can't figgure it out, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Results` cannot hold instances of several classes, all of its elements must be from the same type, so `Results<Object>` is not a valid type for the collection.

Your current implementation of `getData` is wrong. You don't use the generic type `T` anywhere in your function. Generic types should be given to input arguments for generic functions. You need to call both `getData` and `removeData` on a specific `Realm` type inheriting from `Object`, since `Result` can only hold a single type and all your types have unique properties, so you can only use a predicate on a specific type.

This is the correct generic implementation of `getData` to query `Realm` for a specific class with the given predicate.

```
func getData<T:Object>(ofType: T.Type, withFilter: String) -> Results<T>? {
    if !checkRealm(){return nil}
    return realm!.objects(T.self).filter(withFilter)
}
```

You call it like this (*the following example was tested and is working with the playground in the examples project from the `Realm` website*):

```
let people = getData(ofType: Person.self, withFilter: "cars.@count > 1 && spouse != nil")
people?.first?.name //prints Jennifer when called after adding the objects to realm, but before deleting them in the example project
```

Seeing how a generic function can be used on `Realm` with type constraints, you should be able to update your deletion function as well.

Comment: Set up an exception breakpoint in debugger and check the type of the elements of `Result`. Have you even checked if `getData` is working? It seems to me like you are not actually calling it on any exact types. This is not the way to create a generic function. `T` should be the type constraint of an input argument that you send to `getData` to fetch the instances of a single class.

Comment: As I mention on the question, when i define the type as {Results<MyCustomObject>?} works fine, so the question really is how can I declare the type of results when calling the {removedata} function, instead of writing many different {removedata} functions, one for each type.

Comment: Now it works fine and much more elegantly. Thank you for your time. Since your answer will be the aprooved one, if you care to correct the first part of your post that didn't work it would be nice :). All the best

Comment: Glad I could help. I have removed the irrelevant parts.

Answer (score 0):

use this extension to convert results to real object

```
  extension Results {
        func toArray<T>(ofType: T.Type) -> [T] {
            var array = [T]()
            for i in 0 ..< count {
                if let result = self[i] as? T {
                    array.append(result)
                }
            }
            return array
        }
    }
```

how to use in code

```
   let orjObjs = realm.objects(UrObj.self).toArray(ofType: UrObj.self) as [UrObj]
```

Comment: Firstly, there is no need to convert the `Result` collection into `Array`. Secondly, your extension is not needed at all, since converting `Result` to `Array` can be done using the built in `Array` initializer, `Array(Result<T>)`. More specifically, `Array(realm.objects(MyType.self))` return an object of type `Array<MyType>`.